# Front-end image upload from TinyME

Tags: tinymce, uploads, front-end, plugin-tinymce

I'm trying to edit the [Q&A Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qa/) (which for those of you that don't know it is a StackExchange-style plugin with Custom Post Types of Questions and Answers) to incorporate image uploads.

It seems to use the built-in TinyMCE editor that came bundled with recent versions of WP.

This comes with the "Media Library" buttons. Unfortunately, these only appear to be accessible to users with author privileges.

If I can, I'd like to open this up to registered users. I can use the answer provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42447/6344) to limit this to "upload" rather than for users to be able to access the Media Library, but **I can't find what to change in the Q&A plugin to allow this**.

Alternatively, I'd be happy to install a TinyMCE plugin to allow basic image uploads. I tried the [jbimages plugin for TinyMCE](http://justboil.me/tinymce-images-plugin/) and wrote my own simple function to incorporate it with WordPress. The icon displayed, but the plugin itself seemed broken - it was listing strings like `{variables}` instead of the actual variables.

Does anyone have a viable solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution may be to download the [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) and then give the `subscriber` permission to `upload_files`

Comment: You have no idea how much time you've just saved me!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a role editor plugin to give the "subscriber" role upload privildges (upload_files): http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/