# How to safely allow user upload on CPTs?

Tags: uploads, security, capabilities

I have a form with a WP Media to allow user uploads for a custom post type on the front end. Every time I try to upload as a user I can the message `You don't have permission to attach files to this post.`

Investigating it further, I get denied action in the file `ajax-actions.php` where it checks `current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )` before uploading the file. I've bent myself backwards trying to user `user_has_cap` filter to allow user to this action, but it looks awfully unsecured:

```
public function allow_user_to_upload( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {

    if ( $args[2] != 9 ) // 9 is the post_id where the form is
        return $allcaps;

    foreach ($caps as $cap ) {
        $allcaps[$cap] = true;
    }

    return $allcaps;

} add_filter( 'user_has_cap', array( $this, 'allow_user_to_upload'), 100, 3 );
```

This works but it looks terribly unsecured. There must be a better way to do this, please help!!!

Comment: At first glance this looks like it is allowing users to do _anything_ with that particular post. You probably need to find a way to check in this function that all they're doing is uploading something - and you probably want to check also that what they're uploading is safe.

Comment: Would this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/handling-front-end-file-uploads-considering-safety-and-ease-of-use

Comment: Yep Tim, that's the problem, it is allowing users to do anything to that post. I tried checking for the cap `edit_post` since that's what it is called for in the `ajax-actions.php` file, but it denies on `unfiltered_html` cap first. If I try to allow `unfiltered_html` then it fails on a different capability and so on... I've never used this filter before, so I don't really know what i am doing. Fsenna, thanks for your link, I didn't see anything on user capabilities but I will study it further, I'll probably learn something new.

Comment: What kind of user is? Has he [`upload_files` capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#upload_files)? Are you mapping the capabilities of the CPT to deafult "post" or are you using custom [`capability_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#capability_type)?

Comment: @cybmeta, answering your questions, the user has `customer` role, the CPT's capabilities are mapped to `post` and `customer` role has `upload_files` capability. Like I said, I don't know how to work around this while keeping everything in the safe side. A page ( of the post_type 'page') holds the form to submit the CPT, so when `current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)` is called, `$post_id` is a type of `page` post_type, and customers aren't allowed to edit, which makes sense the denial... but yet there must be a way to safely accept such request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the situation described in the question and its comments, the user has capabilities to upload files and to edit your post type, so you shouldn't be fitering capabilities, the user already has the correct capabilities.

The problem is that `wp_editor()` use the global `$post` by default, and in your context the global `$post` is for the page where you embed the editor.

The solution: set the global `$post` to the post being edited before executing `wp_editor()`:

```
global $post;
// Set the global post to your post object
// Exmple if the ID of your post is 2
$post = get_post( 2 );
wp_editor();
```

If you are in a new post form:

```
global $post;
// Get default post object of my_post_type
$post = get_default_post_to_edit( 'my_post_type', true );
wp_editor();
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you @cybmeta!!! This solved part of the problem. I ultimately had to change the CPT's `capability_type` argument from `post` to `my-cpt-slug` and allow users to the capability `edit_published_{my-cpt-slug}`. When uploading a file, WP first checks for the permission `upload_files` and then `edit_posts` and `edit_published_post` and so on (if more are applicable)... The plugin I am using was creating a conflict because it has its on custom capabilities internally and yet it's capability type is mapped to `post`... creating inconsistencies and conflict. Finally got roles & caps down!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow user to upload files. `edit_post` is wrong cap to check. Instead you will need to add cap `upload_files` to users and check against it. If you want to allow only images you may custom filer the allowed MIME type.

See more at https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#upload_files

Comment: Thanks @Sisir! I know what you are saying, and I agree, however, the async upload action in `ajax-actions.php` checks first for the capabiltiy `upload_files` and then after it checks for `edit_post`. This is in the WP core, I shouldn't have to hack it, you know.

Comment: What happens if you set `$allcaps['upload_files'] = true;` and return it from the filter? Instead of setting everything as true.